# multiple buttons scanning barcodes zxing

Tags: android, zxing

I am using zxing for scanning barcodes.  I need to use 2 buttons for scanning.  one will do one task when barcode is scanned and the other will do something else. I want to handle the click like this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.scanone:
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            break;

        case R.id.scantwo:
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

How can I differentiate which button was called in `onActivityResult()` method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {}
```

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java I think you can't, you'll have to fork the library and add your modifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may add a class-scope variable that will store the MODE or TYPE you are running, on each button set a different value for this variable, and `onActivityResult()` based on that variable, you decide how to process the result.

ex,

```
//class scope
int mode = 0;
```

onClick will be like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.scanone:
            mode = 1;
            break;

        case R.id.scantwo:
            mode = 2;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //starting scanner code is the same, no need to write it in each case:
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

and onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    //if resultCode OK...
    //if scan result not null...

    if(mode == 1){
        doActionOne();
    }else if (mode == 2){
        doActionTwo();
    }
}
```

***you may need this, and you may not:***

**sometimes**, `mode` value might get lost, because the activity is paused and resumed, so you may want to save the activity state (at least mode) using `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: thank you yazan. I ended up doing something like this.